# __init__ called when calling filter on foreign key concatenation

Tags: django, django-models

I'm really baffled by this one:

I have 3 models, chained together by foreign keys:

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class B(models.Model):
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class C(models.Model):
  b = models.ForeignKey(B)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)      

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    super(C, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.name = 'inited'
```

When I try to get a list of all instances of C that point to a certain instance of A, C's `__init__` gets called:

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):
  def test_goes_to_init(self):
    a = A(name = 'a')
    a.save()
    b = B(name = 'b', a = a)
    b.save()
    c = C(name = 'c', b = b)
    c.save()
    cs = C.objects.all().filter(b__a=a)
    arr = [i for i in cs] # Here C's __init__ gets called
    self.assertEqual(arr.__len__(), 1)
```

Why should that be? Is there a way for generating the array w/o calling `__init__`? In my real application the `__init__` function is very slow, and should be called rarely.

Here's the back trace from the debugging session:

```
  /home/ranmoshe/sites/django/testttt/testing123/tests.py(13)test_goes_to_init()
-> arr = [i for i in cs]
  /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py(106)_result_iter()
-> self._fill_cache()
  /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py(760)_fill_cache()
-> self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())
  /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py(282)iterator()
-> obj = self.model(*row[index_start:aggregate_start])
> /home/ranmoshe/sites/django/testttt/testing123/models.py(16)__init__()
-> super(C, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: _"`__init__`... should be called rarely""_. When should it be called?

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` will be called each time the python instance is created.  You are probably trying to execute the code when the database record is saved.  For this, you should [override your model's `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods):

```
class C(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()
        super(C, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.The code was called after the objects were safely stored in the database, and turns out this is standard behavior - the objects are reconstructed (with __init__) when retrieving them from the DB, not sure why. To go around this problem, I changed my __init__ to take the values from the original DB stored instance, instead of going through the the original initiation process - and that solved the problem.